# Complete "Scala Logging" Example

Tags: scala, logging

I'm trying to use Typesafe's [Scala Logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging) but couldn't get it to print any debug message. I expect Scala Logging to print debug message to the default screen but it doesn't work. A complete example would be very helpful or specific advise what to change would be great too. I use Scala 2.11. Here is what I did:

1. I added the dependency to build.sbt:

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.1.0"
   ```

   Even though I'm not sure if this is required, I added the following line but it didn't do any difference:

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" % "scala-logging-slf4j_2.11" % "2.1.2"
   ```
2. This is how my class looks like basically:

   ```
   import com.typesafe.scalalogging._

   class MyClass extends LazyLogging {
     // ...
     logger.debug("Here goes my debug message.")
     // ...
   }
   ```
3. I discovered the file ./src/main/resources/logback.xml but am not sure which module installed it and if its relevant. I changed the log level to "debug" without effect.

   ```
   <configuration>

     <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
       <!-- encoders are assigned the type
            ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
       <encoder>
         <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
       </encoder>
     </appender>

     <logger name="scala.slick" level="DEBUG"/>

     <root level="debug">
       <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
     </root>
   </configuration>
   ```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IIRC it'll print messages starting from info level by default. To change this, you need to put `logback.xml` file into `src/main/resources` (or use `-Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml` JVM parameter). See [Configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) chapter in Logback documentation.

Comment: Actually I already have the appropriate file 'logback.xml'. It still doesn't print any debug messages. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Try adding `libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2"` to build.sbt. You should also remove the old version (`"scala-logging-slf4j_2.11" % "2.1.2"`); they could conflict.

Comment: Yes, adding `libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2"` solves it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there some documentation for this? debug log level does not work for me as well.

Comment: My logger is working but now I want to ship my code to one of my friend, but I don't know how to update value inside file tag <file>/path/to/file.log</file> in logback.xml by scala code at runtime. Can anyone please let me know how to accomplish that?

Comment: @Vinay You should ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 73):

For those who're still struggling for how to make your scala-logging work in your sbt project. They just need to follow these steps:

1. Add these two dependencies in your `build.sbt`:

   ```
   libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.1.0"
   libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2"
   ```
2. Create a file **logback.xml** in your /src/main/resources/ and paste below mentioned content in that file.

   ```xml
   <configuration>
       <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
           <encoder>
               <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
           </encoder>
       </appender>

       <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
           <!-- path to your log file, where you want to store logs -->
           <file>/Users/yourusername/test.log</file>
           <append>false</append>
           <encoder>
               <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
           </encoder>
       </appender>

       <root level="debug">
           <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
           <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
       </root>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. Extend your Scala class or object with trait `LazyLogging`:

   ```scala
   import com.typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j.LazyLogging
   class MyClass extends LazyLogging {
     logger.debug("This is very convenient ;-)")
   }
   ```
4. It's done.

P.S: Only a side note that **logger** is already a member of trait LazyLogging so you don't need to create it (as shown in above example)

Comment: `import com.typesafe.scalalogging.LazyLogging` is what works for me.

Comment: logger.debug is working fine, Is there a way we can get println also write to the same file?

Answer (score 5):

You're close, but you have to declare a `logger` instance using an SLF4J logger in the `apply` method for the `Logger` companion in `com.typesafe.scalalogging`. In your `build.sbt` include:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.10"
```

Then this will work:

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging._
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class MyClass extends LazyLogging {
  // ...
  val logger = Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass))
  logger.debug("Here goes my debug message.")
  // ...
}
```

[Here](http://slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html) is a reference for LoggerFactory. Hope it helps!

Comment: The `LazyLogging` trait [already includes a `logger` member that is an instance of the SLF4J Logger class](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging/blob/5b45f24a35d0a4ee560cc3148bb63dde88047ede/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/scalalogging/Logging.scala#L27-L28), so I don't think this is it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it doesn't work for me. 'logger' is already defined in trait 'LazyLogging'. So I renamed 'logger' to 'mylogger' which compiles but still no debug messages are printed.