# How to configure logback.xml for JAR application?

Tags: java, scala, logback

I am writing Scala application using logback for logging. I want to configure logback so that when I run my application JAR file I can get a log file. This is my current configuration, which cannot produce any log file

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <!-- path to your log file, where you want to store logs -->
        <file>./log/test.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Here is my build sbt:

```
name := "distributed-sorting"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.8.1" % "test"
)
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.5.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "0.4.3"
```

Thank you

Comment: Is your logback.xml in the classpath ?

Comment: Use the Standard Out printout to find out what your path for the executable is.  Most likely the log file **is** being created, but in a folder you do not expect.

Comment: try set absolute path :<file>/log/test.log</file>. And run again and check?

Comment: @Berger: Oh, I put it on resources dir when I code, but running application I do not attach my logback.xml to classpath. Is that the problem

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors: I use `scala -classpath ... <my app jar>` to run the application, so where should the log file is created?

Comment: @DaiKaixian: Thank you, I will try it

Comment: Did you create a maven project？I think it may has nothing with scala.

Comment: @DaiKaixian: I don't use maven, I use sbt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29065603/complete-scala-logging-example   this may help

Comment: And  show me your build.sbt

Comment: @DaiKaixian: Hi, this is my build sbt:
`name := "distributed-sorting"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

//libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-pickling" % "0.10.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.8.1" % "test"
)
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.7"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.5.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "0.4.3"`

Comment: So difficult to read. Please update your question and  add the  build.sbt

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about it

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Did you try this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32003907/6037575

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129242/discussion-between-dai-kaixian-and-hminle).

Comment: @JavaNoob you'd better not use relative path  https://dzone.com/articles/do-not-use-relative-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the log configuration file is in main/src/resources and named logback.xml This is the default path.

If the logback.xml is placed elsewhere, give the path in build.sbt file as:

```
resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "yourFilePath"
```

When you run sbt run, check if the xx.xml file present in target/scala.XX/classes folder.

Use sbt assembly plugin or package to build your jar and execute

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=xx.xml -Dfile.ending=UTF8  -cp $SCALA_HOME/lib/scala-library.jar  -jar myProject.jar -Dconfig.file=application.conf
```