# Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" message error from SLF4J

Tags: scala, log4j, akka, slf4j

I am developing a simple server using Akka and Akka-http.

I always get following error message in stdout when I run application into IntelliJ:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I have the following dependencies in build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.1'
compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.12:2.4.17'
compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.12:2.4.17'
compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-http_2.12:10.0.4'
compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-http-spray-json_2.12:10.0.4'
compile 'com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.12:2.4.17'
```

And I have application.conf as given below:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "INFO"
  stdout-loglevel = "INFO"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
  ...
}
```

And finally, I am using Logging like this:

```
object HttpServer extends App with JsonSupport {
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  val config = ConfigFactory.load()

  implicit val system = ActorSystem(config.getString("application.actor-system"))
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  // needed for the future flatMap/onComplete in the end
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

  val logger = Logging(system, getClass)
```

Can anyone know why I always get that errors statements?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to provide a SLF4J backend - Akka [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/logging.html#SLF4J) recommend Logback.

This is achieved by adding it to your dependencies as per below. You might want to flag the dependency as `Runtime` as well, as it will not be needed compile-time.

```
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3" % Runtime
```

Please note this is not a specific requirement of Akka.
**[SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) is only a facade and always requires a logging backend.**

Also note that, in case you choose Logback, it is recommended to provide a `logback.xml` file with your logging settings, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32003907) for a reference.

All you need to know about logging within Akka is in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/logging.html).

Comment: This worked for me - got rid of the warning but instead I got several screens worth of debug and info logs. The docs link in the above answer helps, as does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32003907) (basically, add `logback.xml` and configure as needed).

Comment: "SLF4J is only a facade and always requires a logging backend." This statement is very important. Specially for those who come from other languages, like Python, Java logging presents a truly hell, due to its lack of pragmatism around the subject and statements like, helps a lot. Thank you, Stefano.